# Why is git ssh used for single sign on

Tags: git, ssh

In my office, they have started using single sign on for all Atlassian products, but because of this , those who have cloned git using https have started facing issues. Though it have fixed it by making the clone url as the ssh one, but still i am unable to understand why it happened at the first place?

Comment: "...have started facing issues" This is pretty vague.  Please [edit] your question to describe the problem in more detail. What issues? What happens when they try? What errors are they getting?

Answer (score 0):

Using [SSH key](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/) is one of the solution proposed by [How to do Git operations with Bitbucket and SAML SSO](https://wiki.resolution.de/doc/saml-sso/latest/all/knowledgebase-articles/technical/how-to-do-git-operations-with-bitbucket-and-saml-sso)

I would also consider using [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/personal-access-tokens-939515499.html), which will act as a password.

That means if a user had cached (using a [credential helper](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage)) their *password* instead of the new PAT, said password would no longer work with SSO active: hence the "issues" they were facing.

They need to [remove their credentials from the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15381198/6309), and enter them again (using the PAT as password).